# SharePoint Online list conditional formula

Tags: formula, sharepoint-online

[Screenshot of List Form elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOBCj.png)

In the SharePoint Online list form, when creating a new record, I am attempting to hide the "Priority" select element, but the formula is not hiding the field.

Using this formula, it looks correct, however it is not hiding the element.

`=if( [$category] == 'Select Choice', 'false','true' )`

My question is, does conditional formulas only work on single line of text fields?
Also, if there is a conditional formula for select fields, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The formula you provided looks correct,make sure that the internal name of the 'Category' column is correct and matches the one you are using in the formula.
As [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#get-started-with-conditional-formulas) said:

> The column is represented by specifying the internal name of the field
> surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign:
> [$InternalName]. For example, to get the value of a field with an
> internal name of "ProductName", use [$ProductName].

Conditional formulas work with various column types, including choice fields.

Regarding how to obtain the internal name of a column, you can refer to Ganesh's blog:
https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/